# how to import and display images from a folder using cv2 in python

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I tried to implement this piece of code

```
import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\\Users\\DELL\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\New folder\\*.jpg")]
cv2.imshow(images,mat=0)
```

But its showing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\learn\project3.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow(images,mat=0)
TypeError: Can't convert object of type 'list' to 'str' for 'winname'
```

Can anyone please help me out to resolve this problem.

Comment: you are passing list(images) to `cv2.imshow(images,mat=0)` , pls loop and show one image at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\*.jpg")] 

for i in range(len(images)):
    cv2.imshow("IMG"+str(i), images[i])    # the arguments of imshow are (name of image, image object)
```

Hope this works!

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer, if you find it helpful :)